# Why is Chrome on Android sending my HTTP requests to an IP owned by DoD?

Tags: https

When I make http requests to my website with Chrome Browser on android 6.0 (Nexus6) I saw that it is making requests to 130.90.151.44 instead of the IP of my webserver.

If I use another browser, it is connecting directly to my address.

If I use https, or ssh or antoher encrypted protocol, it seemt to go directly to my IP.

I did a IP lookup on 130.90.151.44 and saw it is owned by DoD

> OrgName:        DoD Network Information Center OrgId:          DNIC
>   Address:        3990 E. Broad Street City:           Columbus
>   StateProv:      OH PostalCode:     43218 Country:        US RegDate:
>   Updated:        2011-08-17 Ref:
>   http://whois.arin.net/rest/org/DNIC

Is the DoD sniffing my traffic?

Comment: Is your phone rooted? Also, there's a long information on the same issue posted by another user on this XDA thread http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2610968 The OP says that a possible reason might be because his phone is rooted which caused this. Try using the a different SIM and check if the same happens. Also, he has [mentioned that](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=50717021&postcount=14) that its T-Mobile servers' IP lookup on his another reply.

Comment: Are you using data compression? Maybe Google is using IP addresses that  have belonged to DoD recently and the WhoIs did not update the information.

Comment: Hello, no my phone is not rooted. I have EU version, not SIM locked. He does not have the same servers as I do. Reading that topic it looks like it is not the same issue.

Comment: @GiantTree yeah I am using data compression. Maybe thats it. Ill investigate further asap.